# Trigger on a view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a basic doubt..Can i use a `trigger` to `insert` changes on a view into a NEW table?

example

```
create or replace trigger iam_insert
  instead of insert on test123
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  if inserting then

.
.
.
  end if;

end;
```

Regards

Comment: You should add triggers to underlying tables used in view and not on views. Can i know why you want to add trigger on view and not table?

Comment: Have you tried it? You should be able to do this.

Comment: rs - the reason im using the view is that are there are two possible events in two tables and i need to join both the tables.

Comment: DCookie- altho its compiling sucessfully, it isnt inserting the data in the new table

Comment: Your triggering condition `instead of insert on` means you don't need to check `if inserting`. You already know they're inserting!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's the point of an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on a view.  You can transform an `INSERT` against a complex view into any sort of DML operation on a base table (or on a table that the view doesn't even reference).

In general, though, it is pretty rare to encounter a situation where an `INSTEAD OF` trigger is really appropriate.  They certainly exist, it's just rare.  If you are trying to allow inserts into the view to insert data into the base tables of the view, I would make absolutely certain that you can't ensure that the view itself is key-preserved which would allow you to do DML against the view without needing to define a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, INSTEAD OF triggers are designed for this. Note that if you define an INSTEAD OF trigger on a view and then perform a data operation (such as an INSERT) on the view, your trigger will run *in place of* the operation. Oracle will not automatically insert the data as it would without the trigger - that is now your responsibility.